# Постоянно меняется session id в php на хостинге [закрыт]

Tags: сессия, php, хостинг

Здравствуйте.
Написал скрипт авторизации. Залил на домашний компьютер - работает. Залил на хостинг - не работает. Обнаружил что на хостинге при обновлении страницы и переходе с одной на другую постоянно меняется session id. На домашнем компьютере подобного не происходит.
[Домашний компьютер](http://temoffey.dyndns.org/dep104/index.php)  
[Сайт на хостинге](http://dep104.ru/)
Исходники страниц доступны на домашнем компьютере по ссылкам:
[config](http://temoffey.dyndns.org/dep104/config.txt)
[create](http://temoffey.dyndns.org/dep104/create.txt)
[login](http://temoffey.dyndns.org/dep104/login.txt)
[index](http://temoffey.dyndns.org/dep104/index.txt)
Логин для проверки temoffey, пароль 123456. 
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в чем причина подобного поведения.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вопрос закрыт. Позвонил в тех.поддержку хостинга, у них был отключен register_globals. Не знаю как связано, но помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`session_start() on php.net`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-start.php)

> To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputing anything to the browser.

Эту функцию надо вызывать **до любого вывода**.

У вас он не "разный", он просто не устанавливается.

```
<?
session_start();
// code, code, code...
?>
<!DOCTYPE ...
```

Возможно, на домашнем компьютере у вас включено принудительное кэширование с большим буфером, а на хостинге - нет.

Comment: Изменил код. Вывел session_start() в самое начало страницы. Ничего не изменилось, дома работает, на хостинге - нет.